# php steamauthentication won't work

Tags: php, steam-web-api

```
<?php

    require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
    require 'steamauth/userInfo.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))
        /*this gives a error*/
    (
          $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
    )
        /*this gives a error*/
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

so i'm new here and i wanted to know why this is creating a error 
i'm making a steam based website and this is for the login

```
(
   $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make block by curly bracket. [**Example**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

```
if( isset($_SESSION['steamid']) )
{
    $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
}
```